# Is there a better alternative to iterate through a large list by first converting it to hash map, then finding object by its id as key

Tags: java, spring, performance, list, dictionary

I am building a Spring Rest application for a food store in which the admin can create new Menu everyday by adding, editing or removing menu items as per the occasion. When the admin tries to update the menu, at the server side I am fetching first the menu item list that is associated with the current menu passed and then converting it to hash map so as to find the menu items currently passed with menu. Following is the code snippet to convert the list to map:

```
private Map<Long, MenuItem> convertIdToMenu(List<MenuItemMappingWrapper> menuItemMappingWrapper){
        List<Long> menuItemIdList = new ArrayList<Long>();

        for (MenuItemMappingWrapper menuItemWrapper : menuItemMappingWrapper) {
            menuItemIdList.add(menuItemWrapper.getMenuItemId());
        }

        List<MenuItem> menuItemList = menuDao.getMenuItemById(menuItemIdList);
        Map<Long, MenuItem> menuItemMap = new HashMap<Long, MenuItem>();

        for (MenuItem menuItem : menuItemList) {
            menuItemMap.put(menuItem.getId(), menuItem);
        }

        return menuItemMap;
    }
```

So I can find the menu item by passing its "id" as key to map rather than iterating over the large list of items. Is there a more better to improve the performance on the server side other than converting list to map ?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. You want a map, and this method returns one. Wht do you want to optimize? Why do you think anything should be optimized. As an indication, all the instructions could be compared, in terms of time needed to execute them, as making a step, except for the call to menuDao.getMenuItemById(), which probably goes to a database, and could be compared to going to the moon and coming back. So, if something needs to be optimized, it's the database query. Everything else is negligible.

Comment: @JBNizet actually while creating the menu the display order for each menu item in menu is associated with their respective menu item id. So as far as database call is concerned, i need to get all the menu items by their id, but at service layer i need to set them to menu according to their display order so optimization is needed at service level

Comment: Optimization is needed when you have a performance problem. Do you have one? If so, have you measured the time taken by every operation, to know what needs to be optimized? If you don't have any performance problem, then you don't need to optimize anything.

Comment: @JBNizet i got your point but i used forEach loop first then i got requirement to change it to hash map as iterating for each object using forEach would take more time than finding object using hash map so i asked if there is any other better way to do this..anyways thanks for making it loud and clear

Comment: Finding an object from a list is O(n). Finding an object by its key in a HashMap is O(1). But creating a HashMap from a List is O(n). So, if the goal is to find one item, transforming to a Map is counter-productive. If the goal is to find several items from the same map, then it becomes useful. But anyway, unless you have many many elements in this collection, the time needed to execute that is completely negligible compared to the time it takes to get data from the database. So, you should strive for simplicity and readability first. Not for efficiency.

Comment: Concrete example: your loop to find items takes 100 nanoseconds. You optimize it to make it take 10 nanoseconds. But your database query takes 100 milliseconds. So, you  got from 100.0001 milliseconds to 200.00001 milliseconds. Does that make any significant difference? No.